# Why is this question closed as duplicate?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, duplicate-questions

[Were the clone troopers aware of the contents and meaning of Order 66?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/110270/were-the-clone-troopers-aware-of-the-contents-and-meaning-of-order-66)

The question is asking if the clones who followed Order 66 were consciously aware of its contents and meaning.

The question it is closed as a dupe of (AND all of its answers) don't address that at all and merely address the fact that some troopers did NOT follow the order, presumably because their chip was broken.